# Swift 3 - Dismiss view controller upon swipe Right

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to dismiss a VC when a user swipes right after the collection view to go back to the home screen. It's a simple quotes app and I'm using a collection view to display each quote on a page (30 in total). Currently I can detect the swipe and get the correct indexPath.row count from the collectionView class. I just can't figure out how to detect that the quote is 0 and if user swipes right again dismiss the current VC. Current code is as follows:

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return rules.rulesArray.count

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let randomImage = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(10)))

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! myCollectionViewCell

    // Cell text
    cell.ruleLabel.text = rules.rulesArray[indexPath.row].uppercased()

    // Change image on specific quotes
        cell.ruleImage.image = UIImage(named: "Background\(randomImage)")

    //detectCell(cell: indexPath.row)

    return cell

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    print(indexPath.row)

    // Swipe handling
    if indexPath.row == 0 {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "homeView", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

I have the swipe declaration inside the viewDidLoad and is:

```
var swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
```

and the function outside is one I've used a bunch of times:

```
func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {

        switch swipeGesture.direction {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right:
            print("Swiped right")
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.down:
            print("Swiped down")
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left:
            print("Swiped left")
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.up:
            print("Swiped up")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

I did try to create a detect cell function but found that collectionView had a willDisplay hook that I thought I could use.

Thanks.